# Impressão direta na porta

Tags: .net, vb.net, impressão

Preciso de um código VB.Net para imprimir diretamente na porta de uma impressora de talões sem usar qualquer *driver* do Windows.

Acrescento que a minha impressora está ligada por USB mas futuramente necessitava que imprimisse em qualquer tipo de porta: COM, Paralela, USB...

Comment: Tem alguma resposta que lhe ajudou? Tem algo que eu possa mudar na minha resposta para atender melhor sua necessidade?

Answer (score 4):

Não posso dizer exatamente para a sua impressora porque não a conheço mas essencialmente você precisa escrever diretamente na porta, normalmente `PRN` ou `LPT1` ou `COM1`.

Mandando diretamente para a porta você evita passar pelo gerenciador de impressão do Windows.

Exemplo simplificado (não tem a qualidade que um código em produção deveria ter):

```
Dim impressora = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\.\COM1");
impressora.Write("Teste");
impressora.Flush();
impressora.Close();
```

Se a impressora USB puder estar disponível configurada como um `COM1` por exemplo, isso vai funcionar também.

Se tiver que escrever na USB mesmo, eu não saberia dizer com precisão o que fazer. Algumas dicas:

- Use a biblioteca [LibUSBdotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) que é um *binding* para [LibUSB](http://www.libusb.org/).
- Utilize *bindings* para a Win32 e construa uma biblioteca que escreva na USB no mais baixo nível que o Windows permite.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/PrinterPort.vb).